# SQL Server OLE DB - select data from DB using RowSet

Tags: sql-server, select, oledb, rowset

I want to ask how to select data from DB using OLE DB CRowSet in C++. How to access specific row, specific column etc. like in ADO .NET using DataTable. Can you give me some tutorial please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article was helpful for me:
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/oledb/article.php/c1119/OLE-DB-Templates---A-light-and-simple-Data-Access-Method.htm